# License Manager

Tags: c#, security

I recently created a license manager for my publicly released project and I just wondered how I could improve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kiwi.Application.Base.License
{
    sealed class LicenseManager
    {
        private string licUsername;
        private string licPassword;
        private string licApi;

        public LicenseManager()
        {
            licApi = "http://example.com/licenseCheck.php?u={0}&p={1}";
        }

        public void assignLicenseDetails(string licenseUsername, string licensePassword)
        {
            licUsername = licenseUsername;
            licPassword = licensePassword;
        }

        public WebClient generateNewClient()
        {
            return new WebClient();
        }

        public bool verifyLicense()
        {
            return generateNewClient().DownloadString(string.Format(licApi, licUsername, licPassword)).Equals("license_okay");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels very hypothetical, and to be honest, there's not much here for us to review... Can you give us more information on the transaction at `example.com/licenseCheck.php`?

Answer (score 5):

#### Naming.

"Manager" smells. It's like "Helper": it doesn't tell anything about the *purpose* of the type, and before you know it it's stuffed with "helper" methods that have nothing to do with each other - and that decreases *cohesion*. Naming matters.

And naming *conventions* too: there's a reason every single type and method in the .NET framework is in `PascalCase`. The `camelCase` of the public methods clashes with what our eyes are used to see, and it's like we don't *see sharp* anymore, and start needing glasses (you *do* know why Java programmers need glasses right?).

---

#### Interface.

Classes describe *types*; instances of a type are *objects*, and objects expose an *interface*. I mean that kind of interface - not to be confused with `interface`. So, the interface then.

```
LicenseManager()
void assignLicenseDetails(string licenseUsername, string licensePassword)
WebClient generateNewClient()
bool verifyLicense()
```

*By looking at the implementation*, we can see that there's *temporal coupling* here: there's only a specific order these methods can be called in for the thing to make sense.

The private fields are only ever used in `verifyLicense()` - why are they scoped at class level? Why does `generateNewClient()` need to be `public`?

---

#### Implementation.

`WebClient` implements `IDisposable`, so if you're not wrapping it in a `using` block, you need to call its `Dispose` method explicitly.

Injecting the query string parameters in the url like this, with `string.Format`, feels wrong at worst and clumsy at best.

This would be a more idiomatic way (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096289/1188513)):

```
string AddQueryStringParameters(string url, IDictionary<string,string> parameters)
{
    var builder = new UriBuilder(url);
    builder.Port = -1;
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);

    foreach(var parameter in parameters)
    {
        query[parameter.Key] = parameter.Value;
    }

    builder.Query = query.ToString();
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

KISS. Keep it stupid simple. What's the task at hand here? Pass 2 strings into a url querystring and determine the return value by validating the returned string.

```
public static bool VerifyLicense(string userName, string password)
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>
        {
            { "u", userName },
            { "p", password }
        };

    var url = AddQueryStringParameters("http://example.com/licenseCheck.php", parameters);

    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadString(url) == "license_okay";
    }
}
```

Well look at that. Now we make the class `static` and then the public interface looks like this:

```
static bool VerifyLicense(string userName, string password)
```

Yes, that's all. No more temporal coupling, and knowing which method to call for doing what, is a no-brainer. And since there's no state involved, the method is `static` and thread-safe.

Your implementation could run into problems if two or more threads called methods on the same instance: there's no telling whether another thread changed the value of the private fields between the moment a thread set them and the moment that thread reads them before making the web request.

---

#### Security.

A web API that requires its clients to pass credentials into the querystring like that is completely irresponsible. These things belong in a HTTP POST request, and your code sends them over a HTTP GET, 1996-style. If you own the web API, it needs a serious look-into. If you don't, ...seriously consider switching to a more secure API.